# How could I override Python's print function to prepend some arbitrary text to every printed line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, logging

We're using AWS Lambda more and we've run into a problem: It's hard to figure out what log output corresponds to which specific Lambda invocation. We see an official [AWS article online](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/techniques-and-tools-for-better-serverless-api-logging-with-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/) that recommends prepending the AWS Lambda Request ID to every printed log line. In their sample code, they manually pass the request ID to every log call. That seems like a pain to do. We have a *lot* of code that would need to change, and it would be challenging to pass the request-id everywhere. We also host user-written code, and would like them to be free to use `print`.

So what we'd like to do instead is make it so whenever print() is called, the actual log line is prepended with the request ID. This could be via monkeypatching print, or (preferably) redirecting stdout to a custom file handler.

Comment: Use the `logging` module for *log* lines. It already has facilities for customizing each log message.

Comment: I didn't say this originally (but modified the answer to say), but we also host user-written code on the platform. We want them to be free to use `print()` rather than the Python logger module. But you're right, the logging module does have some support for this.

Comment: I see no reason not to provide a proper `logging.Formatter` for public use, and let those who want to use `print` fend for themselves.

Comment: Not a fan of that. Thinking about the usability of the platform, most Python programmers are introduced to print very early, and the logger module much later. I want even new users of Python to feel comfortable on the platform. We need to capture their log output too.

Comment: You're the one who has to support it. `logging` isn't that hard to use, and there's little reason to coddle new users in the name of unnecessary flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work. We use `redirect_stdout` to capture calls to stdout, and instead shove them into our PrintPrepender custom class.

```
import sys
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import os


class PrintPrepender:
    stdout = sys.stdout
    def __init__(self, text_to_prepend):
        self.text_to_prepend = text_to_prepend
        self.buffer = [self.text_to_prepend]
    def write(self, text):
        lines = text.splitlines(keepends=True)
        for line in lines:
            self.buffer.append(line)
            self.flush()
            if line.endswith(os.linesep):
                self.buffer.append(self.text_to_prepend)
    def flush(self, *args):
        self.stdout.write(''.join(self.buffer))
        self.stdout.flush()
        self.buffer.clear()
```

Testing it:

```
import time

def test():
    buf = PrintPrepender('6b59c9ff-2be3-4e8b-9f7a-7c018bc4cd38 ')
    with redirect_stdout(buf):
        print("hello ", end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(1)
        print("world", end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(1)
        print('.')
        print("lorem ipsum \n", flush=True)
        print("delor something")
        print("done")

test()
```

Output:

```
6b59c9ff-2be3-4e8b-9f7a-7c018bc4cd38 hello world.
6b59c9ff-2be3-4e8b-9f7a-7c018bc4cd38 lorem ipsum 
6b59c9ff-2be3-4e8b-9f7a-7c018bc4cd38 
6b59c9ff-2be3-4e8b-9f7a-7c018bc4cd38 delor something
6b59c9ff-2be3-4e8b-9f7a-7c018bc4cd38 done
```